# How method overriding works when class inherits class?

Tags: php, class, object, inheritance, overriding

Let's have in mind these two beautiful classes!

```
class Bar 
{
    public function test() {
        echo "<br>";
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }

    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublicn";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivaten";
    }

    public function ShowBar() {
        $this->testPrivate();
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublicn";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivaten";
    }

    public function ShowFoo() {
        $this->testPrivate();
    }
} 
$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test();

echo "<br>"; 
$myFoo->ShowBar();

echo "<br>"; 
$myFoo->ShowFoo();
```

Anybody willing to explain what are the output values and why?

Me having an eye on this code...
It prints "Bar::testPrivatenFoo::testPublicn"! Why?
How am I thinking seeing this output?
Public method gets overloaded, private method doesn't get overloaded.

Ok, so ShowBar() I would expect will output "Bar::testPrivaten"
It outputs "Bar::testPublicn", great.

Ok, so ShowFoo() I would expect will output "Bar::testPrivaten"
but it actually outputs "Foo::testPublicn".
Hmm, why?

Comment: What is the 3rd Foo class? You are messing with private and public methods. Only public and protected methods could be overridden not the private. Also, you refer here as overloading but what you have tried is overriding.

Comment: I deleted the 3rd Foo class. Sorry for the misunderstanding terms, I've just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following piece of code will fire the test() method in the Bar class as you dont override test() method in the Foo class

```
$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test();
```

Hence this method will get fired from Bar class

```
public function test() {
    echo "<br>";
    $this->testPrivate();
    $this->testPublic();
}
```

As you call the $this->testPrivate() it will printout the testPrivate() of Bar as 
Bar::testPrivaten since private methods private to a class and cannot be overriden

Next you call $this->testPublic(). As you have already overridden this method in Foo class it will fire the testPublic() method from Foo than Bar. Hence it will print
Foo::testPublicn

So you will end up as
Bar::testPrivatenFoo::testPublicn

But there is no chance for this to happen

```
Ok, so ShowBar() I would expect will output "Bar::testPrivaten" It outputs "Bar::testPublicn", great.
Ok, so ShowFoo() I would expect will output "Bar::testPrivaten" but it actually outputs "Foo::testPublicn".
```

I just tested your code and got the following

```
Bar::testPrivatenFoo::testPublicn
Bar::testPrivaten
Foo::testPrivaten
```

Please make sure to give the right result